# How to get post url from instagram using Selenium as everytime I do it, it dynamically changes everytime i scroll down?

Tags: python, selenium, instagram

I am trying to scrape Instagram Post on an Account but whenever I tell it to scroll down, the previous links disappears and new ones show up but never all in same position and now it's always capturing just 29 out of 1100 posts.

```
 while(count<10):
        for i in range(1,2):
            #.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            self.browser.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)')
            print('.', end="",flush=True)
            time.sleep(2)

        elements = self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='v1Nh3 kIKUG  _bz0w']")
        hrefElements = self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='v1Nh3 kIKUG  _bz0w']/a")

        elements_link = [x.get_attribute("href") for x in hrefElements]

        i = 1
        unique = 1
        text_file = open("Passed.txt", "r")
        lines = text_file.readlines()
        text_file.close()
        
        for elements in elements_link:
            print(str(i)+'.',end ="",flush=True)
            found = self.found(elements,lines)
           
            
            if found==True:
                pass
            else:
                with open('Passed.txt','a') as f:
                    f.write(elements+'\n') 
                unique+=1
            i+=1
        count+=1
        
        print('-----------------------------------------------')
        print('No. of unique Posts Captured : '+ str(unique))
        print('-----------------------------------------------')
```

This is my code for loading the posts and capturing the links from the posts and saving it into another file so I won't have to rerun it everytime.
the found function

```
`   def found(self,key,lines):
    for i in lines:
        if i == key + '\n':
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

`

I am trying to capture 1100 posts

here's what happens everytime it scrolls down

[image]

then scrolling down this changes to

[image]

Comment: To improve your question and make it reproducible, provide some code please.

Comment: ok sure thing hold on .. let me set it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first find the links and then scroll the page down in order to save the links, scroll the page and get the links that show up scrolling the page. In this way you will save also the links that disappear scrolling the page. Here an example:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10)
links = []
number_of_posts = 1100

while True:
   hrefElements = wait.until(ec.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='v1Nh3 kIKUG  _bz0w']/a")))

   elements_link = [x.get_attribute("href") for x in hrefElements]
   for link in elements_link:
       if link not in links:
           links.append(link)

   self.browser.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)')
   self.browser.implicitly_wait(5)

  if len(links) >= number_of_posts:
      break

links = links[:number_of_posts]
with open('Passed.txt','a') as f:
    for link in links:
        f.write(elements+'\n')
```

Comment: Hi, i've tried it but it's only constantly giving the same links over and over. :(

Comment: hey thankkksss... it actually worked with a little tweaking !!

Comment: You are welcome! If you want you can tell what to change so I will edit the answer 

Comment: sure uhm u add in this
 `all_link=[]
for link in elements_link:
                                
                if link not in all_link:
                    all_link.append(link)
                   
            self.browser.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)')
            self.browser.implicitly_wait(5)`